# With Azure SDK, how to filter resources with specific tags?

Tags: azure, filter, sdk, tags

I am working with Azure SDK in C# to filter all or specific resources, what I need to do is filter those resources with tag, how could I do that?

e.g.
AzureCloud.ArmNetwork.NetworkInterfaces
What I can find is list or list async etc method but no one allowed to filter resources information with specific tags.

Comment: Are you trying in C#? PowerShell can easily do this, if it goes with your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to make it work by retrieving the resource details and adding the condition to match the required tag.

```
class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string tenantId = "<YOUR_TENANT_ID>";
            string clientId = "<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>";
            string clientSecret = "<YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>";
            string subscriptionId = "<YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>";

            AzureCredentials credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(
                clientId, clientSecret, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

            RestClient restClient = RestClient.Configure()
                                              .WithEnvironment(AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)
                                              .WithCredentials(credentials)
                                              .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                                              .Build();

            ResourceManagementClient resourceManagementClient = new ResourceManagementClient(restClient);

            resourceManagementClient.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;
            foreach (var resource in await resourceManagementClient.Resources.ListByResourceGroupAsync("<YOUR_RESOURCE_ID>"))
            {              
                if(resource.Tags != null)
                {
                    foreach (var tag in resource.Tags)
                    {
                        if (tag.ToString().Equals("<YOUR_TAG>"))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("{0} Resource has {1} Tag",resource.Name, tag.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

*RESULTS:*

[image]